# determinant of fibonacci-sum graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices, determinants

We have a simple graph with vertices $\{v_1, v_2, ... v_n\}$.

The adjacency matrix of this graph is $A= (a_{ij})$ so that

- $a_{ij}=1$    if      $i+j$ belongs to the Fibonacci sequence;
- $a_{ij}=0$   if      $i+j$ doesn't belong  to the Fibonacci sequence.

We claim that the determinant of this matrix is $0$ when $n$ is odd. And that when $n$ is even, it is $1$, $-1$ or $0$.

How can we prove this claim?

**Edit:** [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300379/prove-the-determinant-of-this-matrix), the OP added that $a_{ii}=0$ along the diagonal which is confirmed by the OP's observation that the determinant should be zero in the odd case (e.g. $n=1,3$ do yield $0$ then). So in particular, this is not a Hankel transform.

Comment: When n is 1, the determinant is 1.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary Matrices" Paseman, 2013.02.08

Comment: For $n=1$ it's zero because $A_{ii}=0$ (simple graph).  But the general rule
isn't that simple, at least if I computed correctly.  The **gp** program
**v = vector(10,n,fibonacci(n+1));**
**A = matrix(50,50);**
**for(n=1,#v,f=v[n];for(i=max(1,f-#A),min(f-1,#A),A[i,f-i]=1));**
**for(m=1,#A,A[m,m]=0);**
**vector(#A,m,matdet(vecextract(A,vector(m,k,k),vector(m,k,k))))**
yields $\det(A_n)=(-1)^{n/2}$ for $n \leq 8$ but then $\det A = 0$ for
$n \in [9,50]$ except for $\det A_{38}=-1$ and $\det A_{40}=1$.


Comment: The problem is his rule is an algebraic one, and (in my view) does not make it clear if the diagonal is zero (in spite of his words on it being an adjacency matrix).  I choose the purely algebraic rule and am ignoring the graph theoretic aspect.  If you could run the algebraic version (my smart phone has lousy matrix computation capability), I would be appreciative.  I am guessing similar results will occur for this version.  Gerhard "Thank You For Your Trouble" Paseman, 2013.02.08

Comment: That's what I did at first (simply omit the line **for(m=1,#A,A[m,m]=0);**
from the **gp** code).  This gives $\det A_n = 1$ for $n=1,5,9,14,25,37,41$
and $\det A_n = -1$ for $n=2,3,15,23,24,39$, with $\det A_n = 0$
for all other $n \leq 50$.  I'm guessing that the zero-diagonal version
is what was meant, because it matches the "claim" (that the determinant is $0$ or $\pm 1$ according as $n$ is odd or even) for $n \leq 9$,
while the data above looks nothing like this "claim" even for
the smallest few $n$.


Comment: From where I stand, Noam, your reputation as scholar and gentleman are intact.  Thank you for the update.  Gerhard "Top Of The Evening, Too" Paseman, 2013.02.08

Comment: These matrices are quite sparse. I also get $\det(A_n)=(-1)^{n/2}$ for even $n \le 8.$ The rank appears to always be even, which would explain one claim (if true). 

Comment: Here are the first few cases where the rank of $A_n$ is larger than that of $A_{n-1}$ [2, 2], [4, 4], [6, 6], [8, 8], [13, 10], [14, 12], [15, 14], [17, 16], [20, 18], [21, 20], [23, 22], [25, 24], [32, 26], [33, 28], [34, 30], [35, 32], [36, 34], [37, 36], [38, 38], [40, 40], [52, 42], [53, 44], [54, 46], [55, 48], [56, 50], [57, 52], [58, 54], [59, 56], [60, 58], [61, 60], [63, 62], [66, 64], [67, 66], [72, 68], [83, 70], [84, 72], [85, 74], [86, 76], [87, 78], [88, 80], [89, 82], [90, 84]

Comment: I always get zero with the following sage program for constructing the graph http://pastebin.com/0t9GHHzM

Comment: Make the diagonal 0. 

Comment: The diagonal is of course zero since I am first constructing a graph and then computing the adjacency matrix.

Comment: @Jernej: The $n=2$ determinant is clearly not zero.  I suspect that the way you're defining the matrix makes it triangular (with diagonal zeros) instead of symmetric, and thus automatically singular.

Comment: Also posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300379/prove-the-determinant-of-this-matrix

Comment: Probably related: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1209697#p1209697

Comment: If we make the diagonals 1 (see Noam Elkies' 2nd comment above), there seems to be an interesting pattern. Ignoring $n\le 5$, the nonzero values occur only in certain intervals [9,9] [14,15] [23,25] [37,41] [60,67] [97,109] [157,177] [254,287] ... Call them $[a_k,b_k]$ with $a_0=b_0=9$. Then it seems like we have $a_{2k+1}=\lfloor\phi a_{2k}\rfloor$ and $a_{2k+2}=\lceil\phi a_{2k+1}\rceil$ as well as $b_{k+1}=\lceil\phi b_k\rceil$. I have confirmed this for all $n<1000$. Further in this range, for the interval limits we have $det A(a_k)=1$ unless $k=2,4,8$ and $det A(b_k)=1$ unless $k=1,4,7$.

Comment: Here of course $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$.

Comment: And after my above statement, it should not come as a surprise, that if $n_1,n_2,...$ denote the $n$'s for which $|\det(A_n)|= 1$, then the differences $n_{k+1}-n_k$, i.e. the very 'structures' inside the above intervals, clearly exhibit a self-similar behaviour.

Comment: I think I found a quite neat graph-theoretical interpretation, have a look at the partial answer on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300379/prove-the-determinant-of-this-matrix/871760#871760